# How can I get $cgi->state to return meaningful information under HTTP::Server::Simple?

Tags: perl, cgi, httpserver

First, here is the code I am using (you'll need version 0.42 of [HTTP::Server::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Server-Simple) to run it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package My::HTTP::Server;

use strict; use warnings;
use parent 'HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI';

sub handle_request {
    my $server = shift;
    my ($cgi) = @_;

    print $cgi->header('text/plain'), $cgi->state, "\n";
}

package main;
use strict; use warnings;

my $server = My::HTTP::Server->new;

$server->cgi_class('CGI::Simple');
$server->cgi_init(sub {
    require CGI::Simple;
    CGI::Simple->import(qw(-nph));
});

$server->port(8888);
$server->run;
```

When I start the server and browse to `http://localhost:8888/here/is/something?a=1`, I get the output `http://localhost:8888E:\Home\Src\Test\HTTP-Server-Simple\hts.pl/here/is/something?a=1`. That is because `CGI::Simple` looks at `$0` if `$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}` is empty or undefined. So, I thought the solution would be to write:

```
$server->cgi_init(sub {
    $ENV{SCRIPT_NAME} = '/';
    require CGI::Simple;
    CGI::Simple->import(qw(-nph));
});
```

Now, the output I get is `http://localhost:8888//here/is/something?a=1`. Note the extra `/`.

Is that OK or is there a better way of dealing with this?

I am trying to write an application which can be deployed as a [`mod_perl` Registry Script](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/Registry.html) or a standalone application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `CGI::Simple` uses to get the script name is:

```
sub script_name    { $ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'} || $0 || '' }
```

Based on this, I see a couple of choices:

- set `$ENV{SCRIPT_NAME}` and `$0` to a false value
- subclass or monkey-patch CGI::Simple to override `script_name`

Messing with a global makes me nervous.  Changing `$0` is probably harmless.  Probably.

Paranoia means I'd override `script_name` to minimize the impact of my changes.

Monkey patching is so easy, it's seductive:

```
{ no warnings 'redefine'; sub CGI::Simple::script_name {''} }
```

But a proper subclass isn't too hard, and it does minimize impact (but are you likely to have multiple CGI::Simple objects in your app?):

```
package CGI::Simple::NoScriptName;

use base 'CGI::Simple';

sub script_name {''};

1;
```

Comment: +1 The standalone app uses `HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI` and creates and passes a new `$cgi` object to each request. I am going to get back to you once I have done some testing.